# laravel 5 retrieve all attributes from 2 relational tables by eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello i have 2 table **(Users and Posts)** with 1 to many realtionship.

I want to retrive all data in one single query by eloquent and result should be as follow

**Users table:**
id | name

**Posts Table:**
id | user_id | title| body

**retrived data should be**

name | title | body

Comment: This seems an awfully lot like homework! You'll need a join for that and it's impossible to omit users.id and posts.user_id columns due to the way join works.

Comment: yes but how i can do with eloquent, need to use power of eloquent

Comment: how about define the join function in the model, that way you can have 1 liner query

Answer (score 1):

[Eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the data:

```
$data = User::with('posts')->get();
```

In a view:

```
@foreach ($user->posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
@endforeach
```

If you mean you want to make Laravel create just one query to the DB, you can get all posts with:

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', $userId)->get();
```

Comment: It's 2 queries. Edit: nah he needs a join, just doesn't know it yet.

Comment: @devk I guess OP wants to use just one. Yes, this code will create two queries, that's how Eloquent works.

Comment: I know that. He says a) in a single query b) the result should look like that `name | title | body`. You won't satisfy either of those conditions with a relationship.

Comment: i cant use where with eager loaded

Comment: @KareemNourEmam if you're looking for Eloquent way (as you mentioned in your question), use it. If Query Builder way is ok, use joins.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin no i want use your suggestion, tell me how to use where  and with your code i want this with('title','=','title1')

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
User::join("posts","posts.user_id","=","users.id")->get();
```

Comment: but this is a query builder

Comment: Now you're just talking nonsense. This is what you're looking for.

Comment: this is query builder bro i want to use eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following query in MySQL. It should work.

```
select name,title,body from Users,Posts where Users.id=Posts.id group by Users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

In Post model create the following code in laravel 8.0.x:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

In view just call the attribute:

```
$post->user->name;
```